# In App-Billing possible as deposit

Tags: android, paypal, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

Does anybody know if I can use the in-App billing as a deposit?
I´ll explain it, we want to offer a game where users use our own phones, but we want to make sure they come back.
So can I let a user pay an amount through in-app billing that I (without cost) refund after he returned my phone?

I see that google charges 30% in the market for a transaction, how about purchases through in app billing? Can I use PayPal (since google only allows Google Checkout) for purchases of services and activities not software related?

Thanks!

Comment: Creative idea but I imagine this is in some way against the TOS

Answer (score 0):

According to the [In-App Billing Requirements and Limitations](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_overview.html#billing-limitations) this isn't an acceptable use of the service:

> You can use in-app billing to sell only digital content. You cannot
>   use in-app billing to sell physical goods, personal services, or
>   anything that requires physical delivery.

Answer (score 0):

Since the users are being charged against the possession of a phone (physical good) Google allows you to use other payment providers. You can actually use any payment provider out there to make the transaction. Paypal is the first name that comes to mind and I'll be surprised if they don't have a mobile SDK. There are many other options as well.